# How use scoped with sass in vue?

Tags: vue.js, sass

I want to use  scoped to my styles, when i dont use the scoped this code work fine

```
<v-dialog persistent content-class="myclass">
 <style  lang="sass">
  .myclass
    max-width:380px
```

But when i use `scoped` don't worked, what happend?

```
<style scoped lang="sass">
      .myclass
        max-width:380px
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using content-class it means that "myclass" will get added later to a child-component of `v-dialog`, it doesn't exist at the time when it creates the scoped classes. You can only use the scoped classes for classes that are directly set on v-dialog (e.g. `<v-dialog persistent class="myclass">`). All classes inside components need either be set with a scoped class within that component (which you cannot do without creating a custom version of the child-component of v-dialog), or you need to use non-scoped classes like you already have..